# Equation of conservation of mass for isotropic fluid considering external forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws

I have trouble doing the following problem:

> Consider a fluid isotropic in three dimensions such that one can ignore all dissipative forces effect, as would be the viscosity. By analyzing the flow through time of a Cartesian reference volume and the volume of external forces, obtain an equation for the conservation of mass.

Comment: You are going to have to put more effort into your assignment if you want help from us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conservation law typically has the form

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\text{Volume Density of a quantity}) + \mathrm{div}\,(\text{Flux per unit area of that quantity}) = 0$,

in the local / differential version. The integral version is more familiar:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\text{Quantity inside volume}) = - \text{Total flux of quantity through surface}$.

In your case, you just want to take a fluid volume of known mass, with some surface, and take an infinitesimal time evolution of the fluid. The volume and its surface know change slightly because of the fluid flow. You can now calculate the mass inside the new control volume and set it equal to the previous mass. This should give you some relation on the velocity field and density field of the fluid. Put it in a form shown above and you have your answer.